# ReportViewer, vb.net, and PARAMETERS on Remote Server Report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I may seem dumb but this has had me going around in circles.

The report sits on the Report Server and requires ONE parameter "GROUPNAME". my code gives me a cast error when I try to set the parameters.

Please help:

Imports Microsoft.Reporting.webforms
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ReportParameter(0)
    ReportViewerMain.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
    ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer")
    ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/RptTest/RptTestParm"
    ReportViewerMain.ShowParameterPrompts = True
    ReportViewerMain.ShowPrintButton = True


    Dim rptParameters As New ReportParameter(1)
    rptParameters = New ReportParameter("GROUPNAME", "Adm01")


    ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParameters)
    ReportViewerMain.ZoomPercent = 100
    ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.Refresh()
End Sub
```

End Class

This is my code so far.

Thanks

Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem lies in your code itself

you have not properly instantiated the reportparameter array

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ReportParameter(0)
    ReportViewerMain.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
    ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer")
    ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/RptTest/RptTestParm"
    ReportViewerMain.ShowParameterPrompts = True
    ReportViewerMain.ShowPrintButton = True
    Dim rptParameters As New ReportParameter(1)
    RptParameters(0) =  New ReportParameter("GROUPNAME", "Adm01") 
    ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParameters)
        ReportViewerMain.ZoomPercent = 100
        ReportViewerMain.ServerReport.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

you have not instantiated the array for the report parameters properly

thanks

Comment: I actually reckon either not enough coffee or too much. I rehashed from scratch and came up with this:

Comment: Thanks for the input though. I used it in the rehash!